# i think && don't work in javascript for me

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("HRS");
var dte = new Date();
var DayNum = dte.getDay();
const min = dte.getMinutes().toString().replace(/\d+/g, (match, offset,
    string) => match < 10 ? '0' + match : match);
const hours = dte.getHours().toString().replace(/\d+/g, (match, offset,
    string) => match < 10 ? '0' + match : match);
if (DayNum == 1) {
    if (hours < 07) {
        txt.innerHTML = "Ouvre à 7h30.";
        txt.style.color = "#F4524D";
    } else if (hours == 07 && min < 30) {
        txt.innerHTML = "Ouvre à 7h30.";
        txt.style.color = "#F4524D";
    } else if (hours == 07 && min > 29) {
        txt.innerHTML = "Ouvert jusqu'à 19h.";
        txt.style.color = "#4CF470";
    } else if (hours > 07 && hours < 19) {
        txt.innerHTML = "Ouvert jusqu'à 19h.";
        txt.style.color = "#4CF470";
    } else if (hours > 19) {
        txt.innerHTML = "Ouvre demain à 7h30.";
        txt.style.color = "#F4524D";
    }
} else {
    txt.innerHTML = "fermé";
}
```

When i remove all && the code work.

This code is placed in a html file. (between script> /script> and in window.onload function)
This is a Javascript code

Comment: Side note: Don't write numeric literals with a leading 0. It's less of a problem these days than it was, but can bite you in some older environments.

Comment: Converting the minutes and hours values to strings makes no sense here.

Comment: Also you have not described at all how the code fails to "work".  What happens? Anything? Are errors reported?

Comment: So, how i do 07? because 7 = 70 so 14hours is less than 7 hours

Comment: There is no error because i'm in wordpress and when the code don't work, it show a default text instead the innerHTML

Comment: Why "I think"? Debug it and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is here

```
if (hours < 07) {...}
```

which won't work as you make the number/date being of type `string` here

```
const hours = dte.getHours().toString()...
const min = dte.getMinutes().toString()...
```

and with that compare the `string` value in *hours* with the `number` 07, and the same goes for the `string` value in *min*.

---

Either convert `hours`/`min` back to `number` or quote your numbers so they becomes `string`

```
if (hours < "07") {...}
```

---

As commented, if to keep it all as numbers, change your `07` to `7`.

Comment: How can I convert 7 to 07? Because 7 > to 14 in js no?

Comment: @SharkoOts If they are numbers, then no, if string, yes.

Comment: `7 > 14` is false, but `"7" > "14"` is true.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp Thanks...was just about to write that...:)

Comment: @SharkoOts Nobody can say, as we can't see what/how you changed your initial code sample. Add it to a http://jsfiddle.net/ and post a link to it here and I'll have a look.

Comment: This don't work too: `var min2 = dte.getMinutes();
var hours2 = dte.getHours();
if(DayNum == 1){
if(hours2<7){
txt.innerHTML = "Ouvre à 7h30.";
txt.style.color = "#F4524D";
} else if(hours2 == 7 && min2 < 30){
txt.innerHTML = "Ouvre à 7h30.";
txt.style.color = "#F4524D";
}}`

Comment: @SharkoOts Please post code in a fiddle or similar as it is impossible to both test and read in a comment

Comment: Ok, sorry but i think wordpress don't work or i have a problem with a plugin because the same code work in jsfiddle but not in wordpress

Comment: @SharkoOts Ok, then that's all we can do here for now, as we do not know what your "Wordpress" set up does.

Comment: @SharkoOts At least now you have the syntax correct for the above.